# Apache AH01903: Failed to configure CA certificate chain! Restart fixes it

Tags: apache, ssl

Our Apache instance (2.4.25 Win64) throws from time to time the following error:
`[ssl:emerg] [pid 6820:tid 472] AH01903: Failed to configure CA certificate chain!` and doesn't start.

Then I start the service manually (via `services.msc`) and it starts normally. It runs normally and everything seems to work fine.

The configuration for the certificate is in the vhosts.conf:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "C:\...\cert.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\...\key.key"
SSLCertificateChainFile  "C:\...\chain.pem"
```

edit:
my question is different to the suggested duplicate: my config works like 99% of the time. Only when apache restarts itself (for example when a child process dies because of some errors) and it tries to restart, it sometimes (~ once a month) fails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chained Client Certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626027/chained-client-certificates)

Comment: Convention suggests those lines should be in the `httpd-ssl.conf` file, but I have no idea if putting them in the `vhosts.conf` file matters! Did you activate the `httpd-ssl.conf` file, as that has other parts that are relevant to the proper running of SSL

Comment: @RiggsFolly the ssl configuration works when I start the service. the problem occours sometimes when apache tries to restart itself.